# FindControl inside repeater not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, findcontrol

I've got a repeater and inside on of the  tags I've got a checkbox, which `.Checked` property I want to set inside the ItemDataBound event of the repeater. The problem is that `args.Item.FindControl("checkboxSelect");` returns me `null`.

Here is the HTML:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="productRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="productRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="hand">                                
            <td class="hyperLink center-text width50px">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="divCheckbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxSelect" id="checkboxSelect" class="custom" />
                    <label for="checkboxSelect">
                    </label>
                </fieldset>                                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the productRepeater_ItemDataBound method:

```
protected void productRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    CheckBox checkboxSelect = (CheckBox)args.Item.FindControl("checkboxSelect");
}
```

I assume that what causes the problem is `<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="divCheckbox">`, because in the other `<td>` in the repeater (not shown) I've got no problems finding the controls. Any suggestions how to get the control in the current situation?

Comment: But the CheckBox doesn't have a `RunAt="Server"` so how would it be known to the parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FindControl` is only capable of finding server-side controls, not plain HTML tags. Therefore in this particular Repeater it is not likely to find anything. However you can always turn HTML tag into server-side control with `runat`:

```
<input runat="server" type="checkbox" name="checkboxSelect" id="checkboxSelect" class="custom" />
```

Now every `checkboxSelect` will be added into collection of controls, and `FindControl` will be able to find it.

Comment: Omg how can I be that stupid not to spot this :) many thanks!

Comment: And btw do you know how to cast `<input type="checkbox">` to asp.net `(CheckBox)`, because it throws an exception there.

Comment: @AntonBelev, this is not possible because technically speaking these are two totally different controls. Your `input` on the server-side is represented with `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox` class, try casting to it.